# The second half of my Lomuto Partition Sort isn't working

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I can't seem to get my sorting algorithm to work. The partition works great, but I can't get the recursive part to work. I know the problem is my conditional value that starts the recursion isn't working correctly, but I can't figure out what I would put instead.

```
    var partition  = function(arr, i_lo, i_hi) {
  var pivot = arr[i_hi];
  var i = i_lo 
  for (var j = i_lo; j < i_hi; j++) {
    if (arr[j] <= pivot) {   
        var swap = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j]; 
        arr[j] = swap; 
        i++ 
    }
  }
  var swap = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[i_hi]
  arr[i_hi] = swap;
  return i;
 }

//1 3 9 8 2 7 5              
var quickSort = function(arr, i_lo, i_hi) {
    console.log(arr[i_lo], arr[i_hi])
    if (arr[i_lo] < arr[i_hi]) {
        var p = partition(arr, i_lo, i_hi); 
        arr = quickSort(arr, i_lo, p-1); 
        arr = quickSort(arr, p + 1, i_hi);
        console.log(arr);
    }
   return arr;
}

console.log(quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1))
```

Comment: `if (arr[i_lo] < arr[i_hi]) {` Guessing this should be `i_lo < i_hi`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Is there a way to check this to say that was the answer?